# Available Dates from Cottage Reservations

Tags: php, mysql

I am onto my third solution and they all produce the same results which all the cottages within the rental system.

It should be only display cottages that are available and are not booked or blocked off.

Am I doing something wrong with these Queries?

[Available Dates with Reservations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6403681/how-to-get-available-dates-with-reservations) and 
[Date Range for Reservations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394723/need-updation-for-mysql-query-for-choosing-date-range-for-reservation-of-a-hotel)

**Query One from Date Range for Reservations**

```
SELECT *
FROM `rentals`
WHERE `rental_id` NOT IN (
  SELECT `rental_id`
  FROM `reservation_dates`
  WHERE `end_date` >= $start AND `start_date` <= $end
)
```

**Query Two from Available Dates with Reservations**

```
SELECT *
FROM `rentals`
LEFT JOIN `reservation_dates` ON `reservation_dates.rental_id` = `rentals.rental_id`
WHERE (((`reservation_dates.end_date` NOT between $start AND $end) AND
  (`reservation_dates.start_date` NOT between $start AND $end)) OR
  (`reservation_dates.reservation_id` IS NULL)
)
```

Here are my three tables I have. Rentals have all the cottages and details, reservation_dates is used for bookings and dates reserved, blocked_date is an extra table to block dates off that cannot reserved. I have started with hooking up the first two tables and I am getting all cottages when it should just be grabbing ones that are available. Looks like reservations are being ignored.

```
Table 'rentals'
rental_id int

Table 'reservation_dates'
reservation_id int
rental_id int
start_date date
end_date date

Table 'blocked_dates'
blocked_id int
rental_id int
date_from date
date_to date
```

Comment: Your second query is using a table called reservations - is that a typo for reservation_dates?

Comment: Seems that query 1 should return exactly what you want ... unless i'm missing something obvious

Comment: That was a typo; just noticed it as well and fix it. I did try both of these queries, both work, both do not give the results I am looking for. They are displaying all rentals when it is to ignore the ones reserved.

Answer (score 0):

I just found what the issue was. Based on the other solutions I followed what they had for queries. When I changed the query to the following layout it worked.

```
SELECT *
FROM `rentals`
WHERE `rental_id` NOT IN (
  SELECT `rental_id`
  FROM `reservation_dates`
  WHERE `end_date` >= '".addslashes($date)."' AND `start_date` <= '".addslashes($end)."'
)
```

The $date and $end were being ignored.

Comment: Thanks for setting my mind straight :) I assumed you had already escaped the variables =(